# Input field in Blazor server app is not binding when button pressed

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I'm facing weird behavior in my app, when I debug it on my PC, works well, when I publish it to Azure, password input is not binding when I press 'Login' button. To bind it, I have to click somewhere else, then press 'Login' button.
Here is my code:

```
<AuthorizeView>
<Authorized>
    <b>Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</b>
    <a class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary"
       href="/logout?returnUrl=/"
       target="_top">Logout</a>
</Authorized>
<NotAuthorized>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="User Name"
           @bind="@Username" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="password"
           placeholder="Password"
           @bind="@Password" />
    <a class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary"
       href="/login?paramUsername=@encode(@Username)&paramPassword=@encode(@Password)"
       target="_top">Login</a>
@code {
     string Username = "";
     string Password = "";
     private string encode(string param)
     {
         return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(param);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the value is only set when you focus out of the input, you should use a approach that updates the value on every key press.

```
<input 
    type="password"
    placeholder="Password"
    @bind="@Password" 
    @bind:event="oninput" // update value on every key press
/>
```